# modulo operation in Assembly emu 8086

Tags: assembly

i have a collage problem in emu 8086  that sound like : AL%AH – 35 + Abh .

And i not know how to make the fomciton modulo in this case because if a try to devide al/ah a have an error .
[image]

Comment: x86's 8-bit division takes `AX` as dividend, not `AL`. And as you may already know, `AX` equals `AL + 256*AH`. That makes the dividend a lot bigger than you bargained for. This is causing the overflow.

Comment: showing your code could help us a bit finding the problem

Comment: You're making a collage of devided fomcitons?